# Removing Obscured Comment

Tags: support, comment

Unfortunately, in error, I have accidentally posted a comment which was not well formatted. Since then I have tried to remove it, but owing to the nature of the formatting, the delete button has been obscured by the 'Related' section. As a result, I am unable to remove the comment.
Are there any means through which a moderator can be contacted or, indeed, are there more direct means of removing this comment?

The question (and aforementioned comment) can be found at:
[Using the rejection sampling with the method of inversion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41127/using-the-rejection-sampling-with-the-method-of-inversion) .

Answer (score 2):

Moderators can best be contacted by flagging the question (or answer).  A link for flagging appears immediately beneath every question and every answer.  This is explained in our [FAQ](https://stats.stackexchange.com/faq#flagging).

Comment: BTW, I had no problem deleting that comment: hovering the mouse in the area at the end of the comment revealed the 'edit' and 'delete' controls.

Comment: It wouldn't work for me; it was shielded by one of the questions in the Related section.
Thanks for that!

Comment: @user9171 if it happens again, could you take a screencapture and post it as a bug here on meta? It sounds like you might be having your div container overflow.

Comment: @whuber Oh, it was TeX markup? Nevermind then. :)

Comment: @Aarthi I have noticed in the last few days that $\TeX$ is not displaying correctly until the page is refreshed: it seems to spill over the right of its box, more so for longer and more complex expressions.  It is possible I succeeded in grabbing that comment's controls after first refreshing the page.  The offending comment still wrapped all over creation, but it didn't block the edit or delete controls.

Comment: Note that for comments, the button / thing to click on to flag is invisible, but will show up if you mouseover the space to the left of the comment; it will look like a small flag.